# Writing in terms of magnitude and phase

Tags: complex-numbers

$$J (\theta) =   x- \sum_{n=1}^N  \sum_{m=1}^M  e^{{n}/ \theta }e^{(\frac {i2 \pi n }{M})m  }$$

How do I write $J(\theta)$ in terms of magnitude and phase?

P.S $x$ and $\theta$ are real numbers.

Edits:
$$J (\theta) =   x- \sum_{n=1}^N e^{n/\theta } \sum_{m=1}^M  e^{(\frac {i2 \pi n }{M})m  }$$
When n = 1;
$$ J(\theta) = x - e^{1/\theta } \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^M  e^{(\frac {i2 \pi }{M})m }}_{=0} = x$$
Therefore,
$$J (\theta) =   x- \sum_{n=2}^N e^{n/\theta } \sum_{m=1}^M  e^{(\frac {i2 \pi n }{M})m  }$$

Comment: **Please** get the problem right.  This is the fourth version that I have seen, all quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $e^{i2\pi n}=1$  Are $x,\theta$ real?  If not, there is no clean expression in terms of magnitude and phase.

With the fourth question, you can factor $e^{n/\theta}$ out of the $m$ sum.  The sum of the $M^{th}$ roots of unity is $0$, which you can prove by summing the geometric series.  Unless $n$ is a multiple of $M$ the double sum is zero.  If $n$ is a multiple of $M$, the second exponential is $1$ and the second sum just becomes multiplication by $M$.  Now you have a geometric series in $n$ to sum.  You still won't know whether the phase of $J(\theta)$ is $0$ or $\pi$ because it depends on the sign of the (real) right hand side.

Comment: yes $x$ and $theta$ are real.

Comment: So there is some simplification possible by getting rid of the sum.  Having done that you still can't tell if the phase is $0$ or $\pi$

Comment: There is a slight change in my question. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Got it! And how should I approach this new problem?

Comment: I answered that with my second paragraph

Comment: I do not understand. How can $e^{n/\theta}$ be taken out of the sum?

Comment: The second version I answered had $e^\theta$

Comment: I am not entirely sure how   $e^{(\frac {i2 \pi n }{M})m  } = 1$. Can you please explain more?

Comment: No, it equals $0$.  The values are all on the unit circle, equally spaced around, the $M^{th}$ roots of $1$.  They add to zero.  You can view it as a geometric series with ratio $e^{\frac{ i2\pi}M}$  When you sum it the numerator is zero.  In your next to last line the when $n=1$ should be when $n$ is not a multiple of $M$.  If it is, the exponential is always $1$.  Otherwise you get some of the roots of unity and it sums to zero.